# Object between two .cs classes?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Can i create object between two classes ? i have a  2 class files. first.cs & second.cs ,
in first.cs class file have (both are in same namespace)

```
public class news {
//some code here
}
```

second.cs class file have

```
public class newsround{
// some code here
 news nw = new news();
 nw. <-- Nothing display here
}
```

When i tried to create object from previous first.cs cant

Comment: Please show entire code of both classes.

Comment: And please try to follow .NET naming conventions, even for sample code.

Comment: You have both classes in the same namespace, but are they in the same assembly (or does the 'newsround' assembly reference the 'news' assembly)?

Comment: Replace `nw.` with `void test() { nw.` and then you should get something displayed. Andre and Habib's answers explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your class levels.I think this error originate in your class level.add those .cs files to App_Code folder.

Answer (score 3):

That object call should be inside a method, not on the body of the class. Maybe you're missing the `newsround` constructor?

```
public class newsround
{
   private news news;

   public newsround(news news)
   {
      this.news = news;
   }
}
```

Also, make sure that they are both on the same `namespace`, otherwise declare it at a `using` statement.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can only define variable/fields at class level. To access the object `nw` you need it to be inside some method